# Unable to use tekstac eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to use the tekstac Eclipse Plugin (https://cognizant.tekstac.com/pluginfile.php/74079/block_html/content/tekstac-eclipse-plugin-2.6.9.6.zip) for connecting to my tekstac server out of Eclipse.It is successfully installed in my IDE but Every time I try to connect I get an error that my URL (https://cognizant.tekstac.com/) is not valid. But I'm quite sure that the URL is valid, because I can call it in the browser without problems. Does someone use the tekstac Plugin an can give me some advice?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't know anything about this plug-in but the URL working in a browser does not mean it is correct for whatever the plug-in wants.

Comment: Got any solutions for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is correct but when you are trying to login through the login token, the token no. changes frequently so I suggest you generate a token at the time when you want to log in that will not lead you to the error
(https://cognizantee.tekstac.com)
use the above URL